# Find value for a nested key in a PostgreSQL JSONB column

Tags: json, postgresql

Given the following json records:

record 1:

`{"Name":{"type":"String", "value":"Person1"}, "Spouse":{"Type":"foreign-key", "value":"123"}}`

record 2:

`{"Name":{"type":"String", "value":"Person2"}, "Sibling":{"Type":"foreign-key", "value":"345"}}`

What is the json query to be used to obtain all values for the key "value" where the "Type" is "foreign-key", irrespective of the parent key ("Spouse"/"Sibling")?

Given these two records, the result should be "123", "345".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, using [jsonb_each](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function and ['contains' operator (@>)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```
select
    jt.id as jt_id,
    (kv.value -> 'value')::text::int as entity_id
from 
    json_table jt, 
    jsonb_each(jt.values) kv
where
    kv.value @> '{"Type":"foreign-key"}'
```